# Restrict the date range to 20 days

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, date-arithmetic

I have a user form where user selects From_date & To_date to search between those days, there is no way to restrict the user not to enter more than 20 days, this must be done in the store procedure.
How can I return the results after adding 20 days to the From_date. The date format is '2015-05-29-06.44.03.956380'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date contains fractional seconds, so it's a [TIMESTAMP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006050) not a DATE datatype. Dont worry about the TIMESTAMP format, because Oracle store it internally always as a number then it is formatted depending to your session settigs, you can use `+` operator to add days to any datetime datatypes (DATE, TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, and TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE):

```
select * from my_table where date_field between From_date and From_date+20
```